# how to refresh a specific div using j query, not need to load anything on there

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I refresh a div on click function without loading any other page within that.
just need to refresh that div on click function .
I saw some where they are loading an other `php` file,  but I do not need that, I just want to refresh that div.

```
 $("#result").load("load.html");
```

I do not need this one .

Comment: What do you mean by refresh div? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: where was the original content in that div coming from? 
jQuery.load is a wrapper for an ajax get call, meaning wheyou call it it will place it's results (html in your case) inside its selector... so that is a "refresh" just call it selector onclick

Comment: actually i'musing a popup video, so while closing the poup, the video is makng empty imean the div is going empty, there is a problem , i cant append that one, so i'm trying to refresh that div on close so i can get the vide back